# jQuery auto save plugin overriding url

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, razor

I am trying to use the auto save [plugin](https://github.com/kflorence/jquery-autosave) in asp.net MVC. Everything works fine except that by default it posts the data back to the current window location. I trying to override url in the view as shown below. Obviously I am doing it wrong since it still posts back to the default url. Any pointers?

```
@{var actionUrl = Url.Action("Save", "MyContoller");}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function ($) {
            $("form").autosave({
                url: function (e, o, callback) { return "@actionUrl"; },
                callbacks: {
                    trigger: ["change", function () {
                        var self = this;
                        $("[name=save]").click(function () {
                            self.save();
                        });
                    } ]
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution as per the author of the plugin and it does work.

```
  jQuery(function ($) {
       $("form").autosave({
           callbacks: {
               trigger: ["change", function () {
                   var self = this; $("[name=save]").click(function () { self.save(); });
               }],
               save: {
                   method: "ajax",
                   options: {
                       url: "yoururlhere"
                   }
               }
           }
       });
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use

```
url: "@actionUrl"
```

instead of

```
url: function (e, o, callback) { return "@actionUrl"; }
```

what gets rendered in the html ?

Comment: Try hard-coding the url you want in there just to check if it works..  If not then it is an issue with the plug-in.

Comment: Url actually does get rendered, the callback function doesn't seem to get called. I am trying read through the plugin code to see why.